# Change width of div not working for child

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-splitter

I have Kendo Splitter with the following structure (simplified):

```
<div id="MainSplitter style="height:10px;overflow:visible">
   Contains two horizontal panes and the splitter element
</div>
```

How do i modify the "Mainsplitter" width so the panes also reflect the change, and the Mainsplitter resizes if the browser window size is changed also.

**Note**: If i change the width of the Main splitter the overflow of the panes in the div gets active after a the first server ajax call. (does this makes sense?)

Comment: Inspect the HTML elements and look at the CSS. What is the width of the splitter set to? Is it a percentage or a specific value?

Comment: The width is not set so it is 100% by default i guess.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or jsBin example?